# Modify src.zip file in jdk folder

Tags: java

Can I modify **src.zip**(it contains **java classes predefined** ) so that i

first **unzip** and then **add my personal package** and **zip and replace** the src.zip with this 
new src.zip i modified.

so that i can **import** them just like any other classes.

Comment: why do you need to modify `src.zip` in order to include your personal packages?

Comment: yes..u are right..how can we do that..? i mean can we?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Java tutorial on the [CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html). That provides an extensible means of adding libraries for Java usage which doesn't impact the original install, and can be segregated between running processes.

> The CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the
>   JDK tools, where to look for user classes. (Classes that are part of
>   the JRE, JDK platform, and extensions should be defined through other
>   means, such as the bootstrap class path or the extensions directory.)
>
> The preferred way to specify the class path is by using the -cp
>   command line switch. This allows the CLASSPATH to be set individually
>   for each application without affecting other applications

You'll rarely have to touch the JDK/JRE install, and I would strongly recommend against it. By using mechanisms such as the above, each app can specify its own libs, and you can swap between variants of the JDK/JRE without having to ensure each deployment is modified.

Answer (score 1):

The src.zip contains the source files not the class files and it won't be part of the built in classpath either.

If you have to import your classes, you have to keep you other dependent jars in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is set the **classpath**.

Of cause, you can add your classes to the **rt.jar** file, but I highly recommend not to do so.

[How to set the classpath](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

`src.zip` folder will not be included in java classpath, yes you can add your own classes in it. But in order to add it your classpath ,it needs to be compiled and the resulting class files you can add use. 
But its not recommended to modify jdk source, unless you know exactly what you are trying to do.